# How to hide div under another during CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The CSS code :

```
.mainDiv{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.innerDiv{
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}

.innerDiv div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}


.removing{
    -webkit-animation: slideout 1s;
    animation: slideout 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideout {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
}

@keyframes slideout {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbr5vf88/) of the problem.

What i would like it to do is this :

When the first red block moves outside of the green block, i would like it to be behind the blue block instead of in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the line: `overflow:hidden;` to your .innerDiv css rule

Comment: This works, cant believe i never thought of that... Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index`.

Example:

```
#somethingBehind {
    z-index: 1;
}

#somethingAtTheFront {
    z-index: 2;
}
```